# How to take a screenshot on Android?

Tags: java, android, screenshot

I am trying to take a screenshot using the code below, I click the button `takeScreenshot()` is attached to but nothing happens.

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();


    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Which error did you receive?

Comment: I click the button im my project but nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Try this, first create class:

```
public class TakeScreenshot {
public static Bitmap takescreenshot(View view) {
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return b;
}
public static Bitmap takescreenshotofview(View view) {
    return takescreenshot(view.getRootView());
}}
```

And in MainActivity:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            Bitmap b = TakeScreenshot.takescreenshotview(imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks im getting an error though. Cannot resolve method 'takescreenshotview(?)' and Cannot resolve symbol 'imageView' pressing alt enter, says rename referance and create local variable imageView. also where does this get saved

Comment: please forgive me. In On Click method i write takescreenshototview instead takescreenshotofview,

Comment: In MainActivity You need create references to this object.
main = findViewById(R.id.main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);